# How can I change the "minimize, maximize and close" icons of a internal frame with Nimbus Laf?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, nimbus, uimanager

I'm using Nimbus Look and Feel, 
I know how to change for example, the tooltip color, by using this code:

```
UIManager.put("info", Color.white);
```

But how can I change the icons (minimize, maximize and close) to another icon/png file?

Here is the the key of the close button: `InternalFrame:InternalFrameTitlePane:"InternalFrameTitlePane.closeButton"[Enabled].backgroundPainter`
the same as `info` back there.

And here is the site with all Keys: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary

Comment: Same as: How to change the default image of Nimbus LaF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a ugly Hack, but works for me.

```
    JComponent     title = ((BasicInternalFrameUI)myInternalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < title.getComponentCount(); i++) {
        JComponent component = (JComponent)title.getComponent(i);
        if(component instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = ((JButton)component);
            if(button.getName() == null) continue;
            if(button.getName().endsWith("closeButton")) {
                button.setIcon(myIcon);
                button.setSelectedIcon(myIcon);
                button.setPressedIcon(myIcon);
            }
            if(button.getName().endsWith("maximizeButton")) {
                ...
            }
            if(button.getName().endsWith("iconifyButton")) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```